# Unable to Attach Image to Form-Data in React JS POST Request to Flask Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, flask

I have a problem related to React JS. I am unable to make a POST request to a server (which is created using Flask) while attaching an image to a form-data. The API is working correctly, as I have tested it using POSTMAN ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W05j5.png)).

Here is my Flask server code (index.py):

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import cv2
import numpy as np
import json
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
model = Sequential()

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# model = load_model('model2.h5')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
model.load_weights('model.h5')

@app.route('/default',methods=['GET'])
def default():
    res = jsonify({'data' : "good"})
    res.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return res

@app.route('/emotion', methods=['POST'])
def emotion():
    img = request.files['photo'].read()
    img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(img, np.uint8), -1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)

    if len(faces) == 0:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No faces detected'})
    # ...

    x, y, w, h = faces[0]
    face = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    face = cv2.resize(face, (48, 48))  # Assuming your model takes 48x48 images
    face = face / 255.0  # Normalize the pixel values
    face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=-1)
    face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)

    predictions = model.predict(face)
    emotion = np.argmax(predictions)

    # Convert the predicted emotion index to a human-readable label
    emotion_labels = ['Angry', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Surprise', 'Neutral']
    emotion_label = emotion_labels[emotion]

    response = jsonify({'emotion': emotion_labels[emotion]})
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

And here is my React JS code (App.jsx):

```
import React from "react";
import IMG from "./static/ankitHappy.jpg";
export default function App() {
  React.useState(async () => {
    const img = new window.Image();
    img.src = IMG;
    const fileName = "ankitHappy.jpg";
    const file = new File([img], fileName, { type: "image/jpeg" });
    console.log(file);

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("photo", file);
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/emotion", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing UI</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Could anyone help me? If you need more information about the project, please ask in the comments.

I am expecting a response as a object in a console.
example :

```
{
 emotion : "sad"
}
```